# How should i structure images in Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, image, file, structure

Have difficulties with structuring images by category.
As i thought I could create directories and sub-directories in @draweble direcory, but i can not.
So i need structure like this.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkaE5.png)

The idea is to get random picture by category or sub-category.
Maybe you know solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create your own file hierarchy in drawable directory :(

If you really need a hierarchy, you can use the `assets` folder. Note that files in src/assets/.. are not given by a resource ID, so you can read them only using [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager), but you can create your hierarchy as it's shown in your image.

> Get the file like by the path : "file://android_asset/FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/FILENAME"

However, you could also use the drawable, you create the "hierachy" by the file name, then you can get the drawable by his name using the [Resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources)

Do something like :

```kotlin
val drawable name = "SEX_MALE_AGE" // construct the name depending on your hierachy 

// The get the ressource ID
int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(
    "sex_male_age",
    "drawable",
    getPackageName()
);
```

Note that getIdentifier() Returns 0 if no such resource was found. **(0 is not a valid resource ID.)**